# Cannot convert value of type 'Result<Data, Error>' to closure result type 'Result<T, E>'

Tags: swift, swift4

I need help with generics and return types after conversion of older (not mine) code from swift 2 to swift 4

```
let cryptedJsonData = packet.encodeJSON()
                .flatMap { $0.gzippedData() } //here I am getting error

Cannot convert value of type 'Result<Data, Error>' to closure result type 'Result<T, E>'
```

flatmap function

```
extension Result {

func map<U>( _ function: @escaping (T) -> U ) -> Result<U, E> {
    return flatMap { .success( function( $0 ) ) }
}

func flatMap<U>( _ function: (T) -> Result<U, E> ) -> Result<U, E> {

    switch self {
        case .success(let value): return function(value)
        case .failure(let error): return .failure(error)
    }
}
```

}

gzippedData()

```
 private let CHUNK_SIZE: Int = 2 ^ 14

 func gzippedData() -> Result<Data, Error> {

    var data = Data(count: CHUNK_SIZE)

    return .success( data as Data)
}
```

Result

```
enum Result<T, E> {

    case success(T)
    case failure(E)
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of `Result`.

Comment: @fphilipe added Result ..

Comment: Can you give us the full code to test it ?
Or just the part to test it (Full code of `gzippedData() and declaration of Data`)

Comment: Have you tried giving explicit type annotations to your closure? I suspect type inference failed to properly resolve the generic types specialization of its return value.

Comment: @Alvae I tried something but I am not sure, can you provide an example here what would you try?

Comment: You are encouraged to update to Swift 5 where `Result` is built-in.

Comment: @damdamo edited gzipdata so u can run it theoretically

Comment: @mentoxska What is Data ? I can't compile without it. I suppose your `CHUNK_SIZE` is a let constant that you have initialized before.

Comment: @damdamo added CHUNK_SIZE even though its just a int, data is just Data object from Foundation framework

Comment: @mentoxska I need `packet` and `encodeJSON()`

Comment: @damdamo thanks for help, in the end I used other Error type and made it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined your own `Result` type, I suspect the problem stems from a type incompatibility between two definitions of `Result` in different modules.

Note that there is a `Result` type already defined in the Swift's standard library (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result), whose implementation is pretty close to what you've posted. If you actually defined your own type, it is then possible that the `Result` returned by `encodeJSON()` differ from the `Result` returned by `gzippedData()`. Unfortunately, Swift handles clashing names very poorly, especially when those occur with names from the standard library.

Here's a way to replicate your problem:

```swift
// This enum is defined in my own source.
enum Result<T, E> {
  case success(T)
  case failure(E)
}

// This is an dummy error type, with the sole purpose of specializing `Result`.
enum SomeError: Error {}

// This extension has for sole purpose to add a method to `String` that returns
// an instance of *my* `Result` type.
extension String {
  func foo() -> Result<String, SomeError> {
    return .success(self)
  }
}

// Now assume this function comes from a third party library that uses Swift's
// `Result` type, from the standard library.
func bar() -> Swift.Result<String, SomeError> {
  return .success("Hello, World!")
}

// The following line will trigger the exact same error as yours, because the
// `Result` type that expects `flatMap`'s argument is not *my* `Result` type,
// but that of Swift's standard library.
bar().flatMap { $0.foo() }
```

Notice that this example will compile just fine if you replace `Swift.Result` by simply `Result` on `bar`'s codomain (assuming you also provide a definition for `flatMap`).

---

If you defined your own `Result` type, I suggest you either use Swift's one, which I guess behaves exactly as you intended, or rename your own so that its definition no longer clashes with that in Swift's standard library.

Comment: Thanks , helpful answer.. made me realise I had to use other Error type to make it work